# Continuous sequence in VHDL

Tags: button, vhdl

This is what i am required to do. - Show the following repeating sequence on the onboard LEDs (Leftmost LED is MSB):
o    0x00 -> 0x03 -> 0x40 -> 0xE8 -> 0x00 -> …
-   LED transitions must be visible
-   Command the sequence to start/pause upon pressing BTN0
-   Upon power up the sequence is paused
 This is what i have so far:

```
entity vhdl_primer is
port ( clk, rst_n, btn0: in std_logic;
       LED: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
    );
end vhdl_primer;

architecture behavior of vhdl_primer is

  type statetype is (S0, S1, S2, S3);
  signal currentstate, nextstate: statetype;

begin

  statereg: process(clk, rst)
  begin
    if (rst='0') then
        currentstate <= S0; --initial state
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        currentstate <= nextstate;
    end if;
  end process;

  comblogic: process(currentstate, btn0)
  begin
    LED <= '0';
    case currentstate is
        when S0 =>
            LED <= '0'; -- led off
            nextstate <= S1;
        when S1 =>          
            if (btn0='1') then
                nextstate <= S2;
            else
                nextstate <= S1;
            end if;
        when S2 =>
            LED <= '1'; -- led 0x40
            nextstate <= S3;
        when S3 =>
            LED <= '1'; -- led 0xE8
            if (btn0='1') then
                nextstate <= S0;
            else 
                nextstate <= S3;
            end if;
        when others =>

    end case;
  end process;

end behavior;
```

Comment: What is happening that makes you think there is a problem with this code? You need to edit your question to ask about a specific problem.

Comment: my apologies is this better? @scary_jeff

Comment: So what's wrong with this code? Compile problem? Simulation problem? Works in simulation but not on the real board? If it doesn't work, what specifically goes wrong?

Comment: i was informed that it was not written correctly. That the button needs to only be pressed once and the sequence doesn't stop. i am unsure of how to change that @scary_jeff

Comment: At first: your code is not compile able right now. Furthermore you are having a vector for your output port. So you can't trigger different LED's by sending '1' to this port, because you have to assign just one (or more) LED's if you try to turn them all on or off. e.g: `LED <= "00000001"` You should try to eliminate your compile error's first and after that you should try to fix your implementation to design the correct hardware. After that a simulation is useful to check your designed circuit for the correct functionality. Simulation is very important to find and eliminate functionality bugs